# Calculator jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I am having some fun with jQuery and I am trying to create a basic add and subtract calculator but I am having some issues when a user adds (or subtracts) a number, the previous numbers in the input box dont disappear and get added to the next function.

how do i fix it?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/8v9zT/7/

here is my javascript code:

```
var calculator = {
    calcArea: $('<div>',{id: 'calcArea'}),
    buttons: $('<div>',{id: 'buttonArea'}),
    textArea: $('<input>',{type: 'text', id: 'calcText', readonly: true}),
    calcStack: null,
    prevEq: null,
    body: $('body'),
    init: function(){
        var self = this;
        self.createInterface();
        $('button').click(function(e){
            self.clickButton(e.currentTarget)
        })
    },
    createInterface: function(){

        this.buttons.append(this.textArea);

        for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            this.buttons.append($('<button>',{text: (i==10?0:i), class: 'button'}))
        } 

        this.buttons.append($('<button>',{text: '+', class: 'button'}))
        this.buttons.append($('<button>',{text: '-', class: 'button'}))
        this.calcArea.append(this.buttons);
        this.body.append(this.calcArea);
    },
    clickButton: function(obj){
        var html = obj.innerHTML;
        var operator = false;

        if(html == '+' || html == '-'){
            if(this.calcStack == '+' || this.calcStack == '-' || this.calcStack == null){
                alert('error cannot do that!');
                return;
            }
            operator = true;
        }
        if(this.calcStack == '+'){
            html = parseInt(html) + parseInt(this.prevEq);
            operator = true;
            console.log('adding')
        }
        if(this.calcStack == '-'){
            html = parseInt(html) - parseInt(this.prevEq);
            operator = true;
            console.log('subtracting')
        }
        this.prevEq = this.calcStack;
        this.calcStack = (operator?html:((this.calcStack!=null?this.calcStack:'') + html));
        console.log('you clicked:', html, this.prevEq);
        this.textArea.val(this.calcStack)
    }
} 

calculator.init();
```

Thank you so much for your help ^_^

Comment: yes, but try out the demo, u will see the issue

Comment: can u put that in answer form with fiddle please?

Comment: Do you mean that `10 - 1` results in `-9`?

Comment: @pimvdb well thats an issue too

Comment: @Bakudan can you read my comment above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
html =  parseInt(this.prevEq) + parseInt(html);
```

and

```
html =  parseInt(this.prevEq) - parseInt(html);
```

Instead of

```
html =  parseInt(html) + parseInt(this.prevEq);
```

and

```
html =  parseInt(html) - parseInt(this.prevEq);
```

The order is not a problem when you're adding. It is when you're subtracting. `(a + b) == (b + a)` but `(a - b) != (b - a)`

### EDIT

Oops, this doesn't seem the problem you wanted to resolve. I just looked in your code and solved the first bug I saw.
You will need to add an '=' button to show the result and clear the stack I guess. I'm not really sure what you intend to do here. To me it seems perfectly acceptable to keep adding and subtracting numbers.

### EDIT 2

I started over and came with [a new solution](http://jsfiddle.net/gwYTW/2/)

Comment: @Jan thats not the only issue. test out the demo, u will see

Comment: i put you as correct bc nothing else made sense...

Comment: Thanks, did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: ehhh not rly, but it was for fun so i might as well choose the best answer

Comment: I like to earn my reputation so I started it over from scratch: http://jsfiddle.net/gwYTW/2/. This is how I would have coded this exercise. It's not perfect but I hope you find it useful (and I hope it works :)).

Comment: @Jan lol u ddnt have to do that ^_^ hehe thank you

Comment: Well, at least it was a good exercise. I hope you can learn something from it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do it like this:
(fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/QWUhW/)

```
// declare global variables
var result = 0, current = '', adding = true

// create calculator interface
$('body').append(
    $('<div />').attr({ id: 'calcArea' }).append(
        $('<p />').attr({ id: 'calcText' }).html(result), $('<div />').attr({ id: 'buttonArea' }).append(
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text(7),
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text(8),
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text(9),
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text(4),
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text(5),
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text(6),
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text(1),
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text(2),
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text(3),
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text(0),
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text('+'),
            $('<button />').addClass('button').text('-')
        )
    )
)

// add click events
$('button').click(function() {

    // if it is a plus or minus
    if (m = $(this).text().match(/([\+\-])/)){

        // if mode is adding (+ was pressed more recently than -)
        // add result = result + current
        // otherwise result = result - current
        result = adding ? result + parseInt(current) : result - parseInt(current)

        // display result in results area
        $('#calcText').text(result)

        // reset current value
        current = ''

        // if + was pressed, adding is true else adding is false
        adding = m[1] == '+' ? true : false

    } else { // otherwise it is a number

        // add to current (as a string)
        current = current + $(this).text()

        // display current in results area
        $('#calcText').text(current)
    }
})
```

Comment: lol urs has a `NaN` error if u click on a symbol (+/-) more than once in a row

Comment: also your involves global vars, which i am trying to avoid