# How to check if button is clicked while text input has focus using jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, focus, textinput

I'm relatively new to code and have been building a little project called http://keyboardcalculator.com/ to improve my jQuery.

I'm trying to add some more features to improve some things - and I've coded them! - but I want to add a button at the bottom of the page that displays a div to tell people what they are.

I don't want to tarnish the user flow when the button is clicked - and a big part of that for me is that I don't want the user to have to click back into one of the text-input boxes to keep doing calculations.

I want the focus to go back onto the last text-input that the user had focus on. This is my attempt to get it working on the #ansinput text-input field (the big one with the answer in):

```
if ($('#ansinput').is(':focus')) {
        $('#more-commands-button').click(function() {
            alert('hello')
        });
}
```

But I'm not getting my alert.

Any help as where to go from here would be fantastic!

Thank you very much StackOverflow!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5490783/561731

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you want to track the last text input that had focus before the click.  So you'd create a variable, store it on focus and then call focus on that in the button click.

```
var $lastfocus = $('input:text:eq(0)');  // initialize to first one.
$('input:text').focus(function() {
   $lastfocus = $(this);
});

$('#more-commands-button').click(function() {
   alert('hello');
   $lastfocus.focus();

 });
```

Comment: Super awesome lucuma!! Thanks very much. Works like a charm.

Comment: Hi lucuma, I'm actually having a bit of trouble with the code.

Comment: I can't explain things clearly enough in this space - so I'm going to post a reply to my question with my problem in.